# process.on('uncaughtException') handling in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

### I have a strange behavior in ES6 modules:

**index.mjs**:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log('Oh no!');
  process.exit(1);
});

import mod from './module.mjs';
```

**module.mjs**:

```
export default 'foo';
throw new Error('I am broken');
```

I expect the *uncaughtException* handler to be executed when running `babel-node index.mjs` or `node --experimental-modules index.mjs`, but it isn't. This returns:

```
throw new Error('I am broken');
^

Error: I am broken
    at Object.<anonymous> (mod.mjs:2:7)
    ...
```

### Using good old CommonJS modules, it works:

**index.js**:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log('Oh no!');
  process.exit(1);
});

const mod = require('./module.js');
```

**module.js**:

```
module.exports = 'foo';
throw new Error('I am broken');
```

`node index.js` returns:

```
Oh no!
```

This confuses me. Is this by design and if so, how would an *uncaughtException* handler work with ES6 modules? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 imports are statically resolved and the dependencies are loaded (and executed) before any code in your module runs. With CommonJS modules, that only happened once you called `require`.

If a module is so broken that loading it throws an exception, no other module that depends on it will run either. This is pretty much by design.

You can however use [dynamic imports](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) and handle errors with those:

```
// index.mjs:
import('./module.mjs').then(mod => {
   …
}, err => {
  console.log('Oh no!');
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation!